# Fabric (python module) error when try to install fabric in linux

Tags: python, linux, deployment, fabric, python-2.4

I am new to fabric tool, i am using python already.
When i am try to install fabric via easy_install , i am getting the below synctax error.

I didnt change anything in my script , i am sying downloded the by fabric code and try to install via easy install :

Please check the below error , and give the suggestion how i will proceed further.

```
[root@ ~]$ easy_install setup
Searching for setup
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/setup/
Couldn't find index page for 'setup' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for setup
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('setup')
[root@cmcibv12 addr:113.128.177.237 ~]$ easy_install fabric
Searching for fabric
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/fabric/
Best match: Fabric 1.8.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/F/Fabric/Fabric-1.8.0.tar.gz#md5=1f195d16b05877767816617749d33eca
Processing Fabric-1.8.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-PoxSe1/Fabric-1.8.0/setup.cfg
Running Fabric-1.8.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-PoxSe1/Fabric-1.8.0/egg-dist-tmp-JzsXHn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 8, in ?
    sys.exit(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.7-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1925, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.7-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1912, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.7-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1929, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/distutils/core.py", line 149, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/distutils/dist.py", line 946, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.7-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 374, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.7-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 609, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.7-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 639, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.7-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 825, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.7-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1031, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.7-py2.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1016, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.7-py2.4.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 68, in run_setup
    DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.7-py2.4.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 120, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.7-py2.4.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 71, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 7, in ?
  File "/tmp/easy_install-PoxSe1/Fabric-1.8.0/fabric/version.py", line 57
    sha1 = (" (%s)" % sha) if sha else ""
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719348/executing-fabric-python-code-on-windows-7.

Answer (score 2):

Fabric requires Python 2.5 or higher and you are using 2.4. See [official docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/installation.html#python)

> We are not planning on supporting Python 2.4 given its age and the number of useful tools in Python 2.5 such as context managers and new modules. That said, the actual amount of 2.5-specific functionality is not prohibitively large, and we would link to – but not support – a third-party 2.4-compatible fork. (No such fork exists at this time, to our knowledge.)

Answer (score 0):

Fabric requires Python version 2.5 or 2.6. Fabric has not yet been tested on Python 3.x and is thus likely to be incompatible with that line of development.